# Cloudinary images not showing up on IOS debug build

Tags: codenameone, cloudinary

I am making an app on codename one using InteliJ and I have some cloudinary pictures that show up on the simulator but when  I send an IOS debug build, the pictures do not show up.

I went to this link https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sizing-images-just-right-with-cloudinary.html and used the same method but it did not work. When I tried to show a local image on the debug build, it showed up but the cloudinary images did not, so the problem has to do with cloudinary, not images in general.

Here is my code:

```
           Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(ObjectUtils.asMap(
                    "cloud_name", NAME,
                    "api_key", API_KEY,
                    "api_secret", API_SECRET));


            cloudinary.config.privateCdn = false;
            ArrayList labels = new ArrayList();
            for (Object url : images) {
                Image img2 = cloudinary.url()

                        .type("fetch")  // Says we are fetching an image
                        .format("jpg")  // We want it to be a jpg
                        .new Transformation().crop("fill")  //  We crop the image to fill the given width/height
                                .width(hi.getWidth())
                                .height(hi.getWidth())
                        )
                        .image(encImage, (String) url);

                // Add the image to a label and place it on the form.
                labels.add(img2);
            }
            for (Object img : labels) {
                Image newImg = (Image) img;
                allImgs.addItem(newImg);
            }
            ImageViewer imgViewer = new ImageViewer();
            imgViewer.setImageList(allImgs);
```

Again, I am not getting any error messages in the simulator and the images are showing up but they are not showing up in the IOS debug build. Please help.

Comment: It's possible the cloudinary webservice changed since it was originally introduced. I haven't used it personally so I'm not sure. Open the network monitor and look at the traffic from/to the app and cloudinary. I'm assuming there would be errors that will allow us to track this.

Comment: In the past I used Cloudinary in a Codename One app using a Spring Boot server as proxy to upload and download images: this solution makes the Codename One app independent from the changes to the Cloudinary REST and, of course, it's more safe, because the "api_key" and "api_secret" are on the server. I published my server code here, I hope this can be helpful: https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/60b57e1541dbb4589b52b29b06dbda7c